# What does the Expression 规格 mean in the following context?

Tags: translation, meaning-in-context

So I tried to let google translate translate some chinese text, and the results were mostly useful, but the way it translated 规格 does not make sense in the context, indeed, all the alternative translations of 规格 to english google proposes do not make any sense in the context, as it seemed to describe the amount of some substance contained in a preparation when taking the context into account.

So how can for example [规格]1g be interpreted usefully?
Obviously the 1g means 1 gram, but what does [规格] mean in this context, and why is google translate seemingly unaware of that meaning of 规格?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

规格 means a standard, norm or specification. In product labelling, it *specifies* and serves as a description of the weight, length, volume, area and other traits of a particular product.

Similar products of the same nature can be differentiated by their 规格.
You can replace it with a more specific word if you know a priori what measure is expected, e.g. 重量（weight），长度（length），容积（volume)，长宽高（length, width, height, 格式（format） or even 形状 (shape) or 性状 (description of traits).
Informally, sometimes 包装 (packaging) can also be used. It can also be a standardized product specification for a particular industry.

For example, you can say

> 这款薯条有两种规格（包装）：200 g 装和 500 g 装。
>
> These chips come in two sizes (packages): 200 g (a package) and 500 g (a package).
>
> 这款连接线有两种规格（接头）：HDMI 或 VGA。
>
> This cable is available in two specifications (interfaces): HDMI or VGA.
>
> 该手术必须使用 10 mL 规格的注射器和 0.45 mm 规格的针头。
>
> For this surgery, a 10 mL syringe and a 26G (0.45 mm) needle must be used.

Comment: The above is a very precise definition/explanation of 规格 (= 规定+格式).

Comment: Cool thats a totally different way of describing attributes of a product...
Not specifying exactly what the number describes when this arises from context.
Seems to me like google did its best to translate but there is no word with this behaviour in english, allowing for specification of a trait of something without specifying the trait when it arises from context...
Thanks for the useful and definitely interesting answer!

Comment: I think "standard" is the closest word I can think of in English - "There is a standard weight in each package measured in accordance with the standard issued by the commerce department..."

Answer (score 0):

量度 for weight in traditional chinese

一公克 means `1 g`

一公斤 means `1 kg`

Answer (score 0):

That could be translated into specification, or spec for short.  On food packaging, it should be translated as net wt. 1g according to [FDA](https://www.fda.gov/files/food/published/Food-Labeling-Guide-%28PDF%29.pdf).

You need to provide more context so that we can translate it more accurately and properly.